# forest with externalization ignores line breaks (bug?)

Tags: forest, bugs, externalize

This code, compiled with `pdflatex --shell-escape` does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[external]{forest}
\begin{document}
this is the line
of text I compile
\end{document}
```

In particular, the output looks like this:

> this is the lineof text I compile

(There is no space between "line" and "of".)

The error disappears if `external` is no longer called as an option to `forest`.

I am using the most recent version of `forest`. The issue, whatever it be, **doesn't** depend on `pdflatex` vs `xelatex`, or on whether texlive 2015 vs. 2016 is used. Loading `forest` with `compat=all` doesn't help either. Using `tikzexternalize` also doesn't reproduce the error, so this seems like a `forest`-internal thing.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Whatever the bug is, it's luckily gone in the development version ;-) ---Which *should* be published soon ...

Comment: @SašoŽivanović With the new whizzy processing stuff?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović You should post that as an answer so that this question doesn't get stuck in the unanswered list ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this as a bug introduced in forest v2.0.3.  It is already fixed in the development version of forest (2.1), as it was reported to me via email by Ulrich Thomas Gabor (forest's package option `external` wrecked havoc with biblatex).

This version of forest implemented an internal file-copying macro, `\forest@file@copy`. This macro set `\endlinechar` to `-1` but didn't enclose it's operation in a group. The fix is to define the macro like this:

```
\newread\forest@copy@in
\newwrite\forest@copy@out
\def\forest@file@copy@#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \openin\forest@copy@in=#1
  \immediate\openout\forest@copy@out#2
  \endlinechar-1
  \loop
  \unless\ifeof\forest@copy@in
    \readline\forest@copy@in to\forest@temp
    \immediate\write\forest@copy@out{\forest@temp}%
  \repeat
  \immediate\closeout\forest@copy@out
  \closein\forest@copy@in
  \endgroup
}
```